# ¿Como agregar registros a un arreglo y enviarlo a controlador por medio de jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mvc

En este caso tengo una tabla con diferentes datos, ya obtengo los datos del checkbox seleccionado pero estoy atorado en como hacer un foreach haciendo el recorrido de cada checkbox seleccionado y agregar en un arreglo junto con los datos de cada fila para hacer el envio al controlador.

Les agradesco por tomarse el tiempo y espero me puedan ayudar.

Esta es la tabla donde obtengo los registros por medio del modelo.

```
<tbody>
                   @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
                   {

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox"  multiple id="check_@(i)" name="check" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].FechaMovimiento)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Saldo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="txt_@(i)" class="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                   }

                </tbody>
```

En esta funcion al seleccionar un boton tiene que enviar los checkbox seleccionados con su datos. En este caso no se como hacer que sea un recorrido por cada checkbox con sus datos y agregarlos a un arreglo o bien si saben algun otro metodo que me pueda ayudar.

He probado el envio de un arreglo hacia el controlador con un arreglo en duro ejemplo: const array = [2,3,4,5]; y el controlador lo recibe correctamente.

```html
<script>
        
        $('#btnAceptar').click(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {

                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        var idCheck = $(this).attr("id"); //Id del checkbox seleccionado.
                        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                        var sal = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(7)').text(); //Saldo del checkbox seleccionado
                        var saldo = parseFloat(sal, 10);
                        var fecha = $(tr).find('td:nth-child(6)').text();
                        var f_cxfecmov = new Date(fecha); //Fecha del checkbox seleccionado
                        
                         //aqui quiero hacer un foreach que lea los checkbox seleccionados y los agregue 
                           a un arreglo para enviarlo al controlador.

                        })
                    }

                    var uri = '@Url.Action("getAplication", "CxC")';
                    var arr = array; //aqui quiero enviar el arreglo con los datos de cada fila 
                                      seleccionada
                    $.ajax({
                        url: uri,
                        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json'
                    });
                })
            })

        });
    </script>
```

controlador que recibe los datos.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getAplication(long[] data)
    {
        using (var db = new dbAsEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
               

            }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a tus elementos check ponles una clase asi haces un length para check con esa clase para depeus hacer un for para hacer el recorido de cada check y a tu controlador envialos como objetos para esto crea una clase que va recibir este objeto

Comment: [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getAplication(string data)
    { 
        using (var db = new dbAsEntities())
        {
        var datos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<miclase>>(items);
  var ListaDatos = datos.ToList();
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
               

            }

        return View();
    }

Answer (score 0):

asi creas el objeto
var item = [];
item.push({
"vchComentario": comentario,
"vchAlias": alias,
"iIdEspObjeto": datos,
"iIdTipoBitacoraModificacion": bita,
"iIdTipoValor": valor,
"bActivo": activo
})

Comment: $.ajax({
                        url: uri,
                        data: JSON.stringify(item),
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json'
                    });